# Unable to get "apply-css" FireFox WebExtension example working

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm a noob experimenting with WebExtensions. I can't get the ["apply-css" extension example on GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/apply-css) to work.

I'm running Firefox Beta, version 49.0b6 (The strict_min_version in *manifest.json* is 49.0). After restarting the browser, loading and reloading the extension via "about:debugging", I don't see any new icons in the page action area. I've also verified that the necessary files and icons are in place.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

What other info can I provide? This seems pretty simple.

Comment: Works, more or less, OK for me on 49.0b6 and 50.0a2. In 49.0b6 I experienced some strangeness in it responding to clicks which I did not see in 50.0a2. As Noitidart mentioned, you have to navigate to an HTML page (not an `about:` page) for it to show up.  Also, the use of a black icon is an unfortunate choice that makes it invisible in the Firefox Developer Edition stock theme.

Comment: I read your bio on so and it seems you are interested in C++ stuff. You would really love js-ctypes. I actually am looking for people to collaborate with on some js-ctypes work. It taps straight into the platform. Let me know if you're interested I can share with you what I need some collaboration on.

Comment: One of my open source projects is Screencastify (to record video of screen and audio capture) and I'm trying to port over DirectShow to capture the audio coming out of the speakers, I was able to route the mic input straight to speakers output but I can't understand the docs to record system sound. It would be awesome if you could help with that, I was working on it here - https://github.com/Noitidart/ostypes_playground/blob/audio-capture/bootstrap.js#L247-L615

Comment: @Makyen- Thanks for the question edit and correcting my hastily made mistakes. I also see how to keep things a bit more clear as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Noitidart- With young kids it's hard for me to work on my own projects, but I'll consider your offer for collaboration. I was wondering how I might volunteer on an open source project. Js-ctypes might be helpful for another project I have in mind. If I can free up a small space of regular time, I'll let you know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me. You can follow this screencast I made to try it yourself:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xouJjHJhSN0

A note though, it will only work if the page is an HTML page, as you can see in the screecast, when the page in the tab is not a HTML page, you don't see the page action button.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I watched what you did and, as a noob, that's much better than what I was doing. I was downloading files the separately and forgot to create the icons directory. Sorry everyone spent time on this. The workflow, as demonstrated in the video is good--that's what I'm doing now. Thanks!